# How can I plot a bar chart showing total sales for different types of store types in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I have a dataset (not the one below, but of a similar kind) from which I am trying to plot a bar chart in Python so that I can visualize the 'Total Sales' made from different kind of 'Outlet Type'.

```
╔══════════╦════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ Location ║    Outlet_Type     ║ Sales ║
╠══════════╬════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ Bandra   ║ Supermarket Type 1 ║   125 ║
║ Worli    ║ Supermarket Type 2 ║   150 ║
║ Wadala   ║ Supermarket Type 3 ║   100 ║
║ Chembur  ║ Supermarket Type 2 ║   100 ║
║ Kalina   ║ Supermarket Type 3 ║   110 ║
║ Dadar    ║ Supermarket Type 3 ║   115 ║
║ Korba    ║ Supermarket Type 2 ║   135 ║
║ Asavari  ║ Supermarket Type 1 ║   145 ║
╚══════════╩════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

So from the above data my bar chart should have on the,

X-axis : 'Supermarket Type 1', 'Supermarket Type 2' and 'Supermarket Type 3' 
Y-axis : Total Sales made from the different type of outlets

So the bar of

'Supermarket Type 1' will have a value of 270 
'Supermarket Type 2' will have a value of 385 
'Supermarket Type 3' will have a value of 325

In SQL terms its similar to doing a 'group by' but in Python I am not able to do so and instead I am using pivot table for the time being.

```
data.pivot_table(values = 'Sales', index = 'Outlet_Type')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the outlet type with summation and plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data.groupby('Outlet_Type').sum()['Sales'].plot.bar()
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]
Consult `matplotlib` documentation for how to enhance the chart.

Comment: Hi @DYZ thanks for the help. I tried it on my dataset and it worked. Did scour the documentations and examples a lot man since yesterday, but no luck. Though now it seems like I was looking at the wrong places.

Answer (score 3):

You're really quite close.  Just missing an `aggfunc` in your current approach, so `pivot_table` does not sum:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data.pivot_table(values = 'Sales', index = 'Outlet_Type', aggfunc='sum').plot(kind='bar')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @user3483203 (Chris),

Thanks a ton for the help mate, it worked. The results in the Y-axis were coming in exponents and due to that the scale got me a bit confused initially, blimey! I did not know that we can actually plot results from a pivot table directly my using the 'plot' function.

Have a nice weekend man! :)